# New array with subtracted elements using Python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a new array which basically consists of elements obtained after subtracting the adjacent elements of `I`.

```
import numpy as np
I=np.array([0.42741221, 0.32863457, 0.03597327, 0.23270579, 0.24660262,
       0.28189469, 0.30789726, 0.26947605, 0.11872097, 0.0089662 ,
       0.3677314 , 0.00606158, 0.2923718])
```

Desired output:

```
np.array([(0.42741221-0.32863457), (0.32863457-0.03597327), (0.03597327-0.23270579),...])
```

Comment: Have you had a look at `np.diff()`?

Comment: Please post the code that worked for you below as an answer so that your question can be useful to other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `np.diff()` helps.

```
import numpy as np
I=np.array([0.42741221, 0.32863457, 0.03597327, 0.23270579, 0.24660262,
       0.28189469, 0.30789726, 0.26947605, 0.11872097, 0.0089662 ,
       0.3677314 , 0.00606158, 0.2923718])
np.diff(I)
```

This yields the desired output:

```
array([-0.09877764, -0.2926613 ,  0.19673252,  0.01389683,  0.03529207,
        0.02600257, -0.03842121, -0.15075508, -0.10975477,  0.3587652 ,
       -0.36166982,  0.28631022])
```